# Can't create proxies of Panasonic GH6 5.7K ProRes in Final Cut Pro

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, conversion, apple, panasonic

I recently shot a 20-minute clip on a Panasonic GH6.  I recorded 5.7K at 29.97 fps with ProRes 422, and the resulting file is about 500 GB.  I recorded to a Samsung 2 TB T7 Shield.

I plugged the drive into my M1 MBP (16", 16 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD).

Macbook Pro is running Venture 13.4.1 with FCP 10.6.6.

Playback of the 5.7K video is really slow, so I set it to transcode proxies at 25%.  However, I've waited over an hour and "Transcoding clip" is still at 0%.

I couldn't believe it was that slow, so I rebooted my machine and tried again-- still, after an hour, I'm at 0%.  How can I speed this up?  I need proxies to edit, and I can't believe it takes dozens of hours to go from ProRes ~6k to ProRes ~2k.

Although it's stuck at 0%, I don't think the process is actually stuck because the blue activity light on the T7 Shield is flickering.